# Looping through 12 months

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, t-sql

I need to fill a bar chart with data.  I have everything in place.  I have the sql query used to gather the data.

What I am looking for is the best way to provide data for the current month and the last 11 months (12 months total).

This code will give me the information for the current month up until today.  How can I modify this so it will also give me the information for the previous 11 months?

Would this modification be made to the query or would we loop over the query 12 times?

```
protected void FillChart ()
{
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime startDate = now.AddDays( 1 - now.Day );
    DateTime endDate = now;
    string query;

    query = "SELECT SUM(case when r.Type in ('Programming-Billable', 'Consulting-Billable') then r.Minutes_Spent";
    query += " end) AS 'Custom Programming and Consulting',";
    query += " SUM(case when r.Type in ('Data Maintenance', 'Tech Support-Billable', 'Training') then r.Minutes_Spent";
    query += " end) AS 'Tech. Support / Data Maint. / Training'";
    query += " FROM TK_Project p ";
    query += " INNER JOIN TK_Task t";
    query += " ON p.Project_ID = t.Project_ID ";
    query += " JOIN TK_Time_Record r";
    query += " ON t.ID = r.Task_ID";
    query += " WHERE p.Company = " + Session[ "Distid" ];
    query += " AND p.Name ='Technical Support' ";
    query += " AND r.Work_Date BETWEEN  '" + startDate + "'  AND  '" + endDate + "' ";
    query += " AND r.Type NOT LIKE '%non%'";


    DataTable data = GeneralFunctions.GetData( query );
}
```

The query currently returns the following results:

```
Custom Programming and Consulting   Tech. Support / Data Maint. / Training
           90                                           105
```

EDITED:

```
SELECT SUM(case when r.Type in ('Programming-Billable', 'Consulting-Billable') then r.Minutes_Spent
           end) AS 'Custom Programming and Consulting',
       SUM(case when r.Type in ('Data Maintenance', 'Tech Support-Billable', 'Training') then r.Minutes_Spent
           end) AS 'Tech. Support / Data Maint. / Training'
FROM TK_Project p 
INNER JOIN TK_Task t
     ON p.Project_ID = t.Project_ID 
JOIN TK_Time_Record r
     ON t.ID = r.Task_ID
WHERE p.Company = 162 AND p.Name ='Technical Support' 
AND r.Work_Date BETWEEN  '04/01/2001'  AND  '04/30/2012' 
AND r.Type NOT LIKE '%non%'
```

Comment: Change startDate to now.AddYears(-1) then add GROUP BY MONTH(r.Work_Date)

Comment: @Kevin getting much closer.  Is it possible to show the current month in the query?  So April = 4, Jan = 1, March = 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to change start and end date:

```
DateTime startDate = now.AddYears( -1 );
DateTime endDate = now;
```

By the way, it would probably better to use parameters for both datetimes. So you should pass them to the `GetData` method and create SqlParameters from it.

**Edit**: If you want to have the sum for each month, you need to group by month.

```
GROUP BY DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, Work_Date),0)
```

You can omit the enddate if you want to get all records until now anyway:

```
SELECT SUM(case when r.Type in ('Programming-Billable', 'Consulting-Billable') then r.Minutes_Spent
           end) AS 'Custom Programming and Consulting'
     , SUM(case when r.Type in ('Data Maintenance', 'Tech Support-Billable', 'Training') then r.Minutes_Spent
           end) AS 'Tech. Support / Data Maint. / Training'
     , DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, Work_Date),0) AS Month
FROM TK_Project p 
INNER JOIN TK_Task t
     ON p.Project_ID = t.Project_ID 
JOIN TK_Time_Record r
     ON t.ID = r.Task_ID
WHERE p.Company = 162 AND p.Name ='Technical Support' 
AND r.Work_Date BETWEEN  @startDate  AND  GetDate()
AND r.Type NOT LIKE '%non%'
GROUP BY DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, Work_Date),0)
Order By Month
```

Note that i've added the @startDate as parameter.

Comment: This wont break down the query into month segments.  The query would return me a sum result for all 12 months instead of 12 different results/rows/columns.  I'm not sure of the best or even an easy way to accomplish this.  I need to fill a table with information for the total minutes spent in each category for each month.  Which then jquery takes over and throws that information into a canvas bar chart.

Comment: You're going to need a group-by, using datepart() on each month, I think

Comment: @JamesWilson: Can you show us the query without the `query += "`'s ? Then it would be much easier to improve the sql query.

Comment: Thanks Tim! Worked like a charm, I even edited it to subtract a year from GETDATE since I'm not giving them control of what data is populated yet.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the requirement correctly, you would Group By the month of Work_Date

```
Group by datepart(month, r.Work_Date)
```

Comment: This has gotten me much closer to the desired results.  Is it possible to return the month in the query?  So April would return to me `Month -> 4 Custom Programming and Consulting -> 90 Tech. Support / Data Maint. / Training
 -> 105`

Comment: Nevermind I have figured it out.  Just added `MONTH(r.Work_Date) AS Month` to the select list.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm not understanding the question, but it sounds like you need to make the start and end dates as parameters of `FillChart()`.

Comment: So I am building a chart that will show data over the past 12 months.  It will always show them the current month and 11 month previous to the current month (current month = the month of todays date).  Because I am forcing them to show todays month and 11 months back I don't think the dates need to be parameters.

Comment: So, you are wanting a single method that returns 12 sets of data, one for this month and 11 for each prior month? I was anticipating you'd call the parameterized FillChart() method to get each data set and combine them elsewhere.

Comment: Yes I'm just not sure if this is best for the method to handle, or if the sql query should be modified to do this.  In either case, I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: I suggest you write a stored procedure to do the work of gathering the data and have C# consume it.